# Python working out average scores from a text file

Tags: python

I am trying to import data from a text file then work out the average of the 3 scores here is my code so far

```
for line in fi:
                column = line.split(",")
                names = column[0]
                scores = int(column[1].strip())

                count = 0
                while count < 3:
                    d.setdefault(names, []).append(scores)
                    count = count + 1
                averages=[]
        for name, v in d.items():
            average = (sum(v)/len(v))
            averages.append((name, average))
        for name, average in sorted(averages, key=lambda a: a[1], reverse=True):
            print(name, average)
```

This code just prints the first of the 3 scores and doesn't work out the average 
The file is set out as shown below

```
andy,2,8,9
john,4,5,8
james,9,5,3
elliot,3,6,2
Alphie,3,2,4
```

Could anyone help ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It only prints the first score because you only take the first score.

Change this line:

```
scores = int(column[1].strip())
```

to this:

```
scores = [int(x) for x in column[1:]]
```

Now, `scores` is a list and not a single value, meaning that you have to `extend` the lists in `d`:

```
d.setdefault(names, []).extend(scores)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this one helps:

```
from __future__ import division
dic={}
with open("filename.txt","r") as f:
    for line in f:
        lst=line.split(",")
        dic[lst[0]]=sum(map(int,lst[1:]))/3 #map is converting string to int

print dic
```

Output:

```
{
  'james': 5.666666666666667,
  'john': 5.666666666666667, 
  'andy': 6.333333333333333, 
  'elliot': 3.6666666666666665, 
  'Alphie': 3.0
}
```

Finally, if you want to sort the dictionary by value (Though you can't really sort a dictionary as dictionaries are unordered) and get a list of tuple, do:

```
print sorted(dic.items(), key=lambda x:x[1],reverse=True)
```

Output:

```
[('andy', 6.333333333333333), ('james', 5.666666666666667), 
 ('john', 5.666666666666667), ('elliot', 3.6666666666666665), 
 ('Alphie', 3.0)
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the use of the dictionary was, but here is a full attempt at what you are trying to achieve.

```
averages = []
for line in fi:
    data = line.split(",")
    scores = map(int, data[1:])
    averages.append((data[0], sum(scores)/float(len(scores))))

for name, average in sorted(averages, key=lambda a: a[1], reverse=True):
    print(name, average)
```

#### Output

```
('andy', 6.333333333333333)
('john', 5.666666666666667)
('james', 5.666666666666667)
('elliot', 3.6666666666666665)
('Alphie', 3.0)
```